Generalized Dini's Theorem
Dini's Theorem says: let $f_n:K\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
(a) $K$ is compact
(b) $f_{n+1}(x)\le f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and $x\in K$
(c) $f_n$ is continuous and there is a continuous $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $f_n\to f$ pointwise.
Then, $f_n\to f$ uniformly.
Now, if we replace (b) by (b'): $|f_{n+1}(x)|\le|f_n(x)|$, how can I prove the same conclusion? That is, $f_n\to f$ uniformly.
It is clear, that by usual Dini's Theorem, $|f_n|\to|f|$ uniformly. But I can't obtain the desired conclusion: $f_n\to f$ uniformly.
On the other hand, in the proof of the usual version the idea is that $\{f_n-f\}$ is a decreasing sequence, since $f_{n+1}\le f_n$, and therefore we obtain an increasing chain of open subsets that covers $K$. But in this case, the fact $|f_{n+1}|\le|f_n|$ doesn't imply the existence of an useful  chain of open sets.

I don't understand the close votes.

Here is a counter-example, showing that (some form of) local connectivity is necessary. Consider $K=\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb N\}\subset \mathbb R$.
Let $f\equiv 1$ be a constant function on $K$. For every $n$ define a function $f_n$ on $K$ by $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\ne 1/n$ and $f(1/n)=-1$. Then each $f_n$ is continuous, the sequence $|f_n|\equiv 1$ is constant, and $f_n\to f$ pointwise. However, clearly, the sequence $(f_n)$
does not converge to $f$ uniformly.
More generally, suppose that there is an infinite sequence of pairwise disjoint nonempty clopen subsets $C_n\subset K$. Then Generalized Dini's Theorem fails for $K$. The construction is similar to the one before: For every $n$ define $f_n: K\to \mathbb R$ which equals $1$ on $K\setminus C_n$ and equals $-1$ on $C_n$. Take $f\equiv 1$ on $K$.  Then each $f_n$ is continuous, $f_n\to f$ pointwise but not uniformly, while the sequence $|f_n|$ is constant.

What topology in K are you using?

@user1476823 subspace topology, of course.

(partial answer under an extra assumption on $K$) If $K$ is a locally connected metric space the result follows as below.
Asssume by contradiction that $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f$ so (by compacity, taking subsequences etc) there is $x_n \to x$ and $\epsilon>0$ st $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)| >\epsilon$. Clearly $f(x) \ne 0$ since $|f_n(x_n)| \to |f(x)|$ (by the uniform convergence of $|f_n|$ to $|f|$) so assuming wlog $f(x)>0$ we get $f_n(x_n)<0, n \ge n_0$. Also $f_n(x)>0, n \ge n_1$
But then choosing $U_m$ a countable connected set of open neighborhoods of $x$ st $\cap U_m= x$ we pick $x_{n_m} \in U_m$ and by continuity we have that (for large enough $m$) $f_{n_m}(U_m)$ is a connected real set containing a positive and a negative number so there is $y_m \in U_m$ st $f_{n_m}(y_m)=0$. But by the monotonicity of $|f_k|$ it follows that all $f_k(y_m)=0, k \ge n_m$ so $f(y_m)=0$ and since $y_m \to x$ we get $f(x)=0$ which is a contradiction!
